# JQuery UI dialog: should I use h1, h2 or h3?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, html-title

Which HTML title tag (h1, h2, h3...) is supposed to be used in a JQuery UI dialog?

I know I can put anything and set the layout I want using CSS, but I would like to know if a title level is more appropriate than another one.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an `<h3>`, or at least and `<h2>`

`<h1>` is known to conceptually represent the *main* title of a page and is the top-level heading element anyway.

> Note: despite the fact that the specification does allow it, it is generally accepted to not have multiple `<h1>` elements within the same page. Using it multiple times should be done carefully though.

Some extra reading:

[Proper Use Of H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6 header elements](http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/)
[The Beauty of Semantic Markup, Part 3: Headings](http://ablognotlimited.com/articles/the-beauty-of-semantic-markup-part-3-headings)